# Insert Multiple Foreign Keys Simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, auto-increment

I have a form that gathers user input regarding a property they showed (a realtor showing to potential business leasees).

Upon submitting the form, I insert the data into three tables: `Showing`, `Business`, and `Contact`.  This form allows for the creation of new `Businesses` and new `Contacts`, while also creating a new `Showing` record.

I can insert the information into either my `Business` table and my `Contacts` table fine with an auto-incrementing `primary key`.

How do I insert the `primary key` from `Contacts` as a `foreign key` in `Business` when they are both submitted at the same time?

Should I have a values table which I select from for both the `primary key` and the `foreign key`? What are the best practices around this?

Additionally, I would like the insert the `primary keys` from both `Business` and `Contacts` as `foreign keys` in my `Showing` table.  I currently have a `BusinessID` as `foreign key` within `Contacts` but maybe `Contacts` should stand alone so that I can `Insert` it first and then just select for the subsequent `foreign keys`?

Finally I should note that for a database I am using `phpMyAdmin` and inserting via SQL within a `.php` page.

Comment: You should include code you've tried. And read up on [last_insert_id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html)

Comment: You insert the record into Contact table, get the last id, reference the last id in the insertion of the record to the Business table, get the last id. Use both last ids to store the record in the Showing table

Comment: Thats what I'm thinking. Is there a way to also insert `BusinessID` into `Contacts`? or do I need one table which has no `foreign keys`? And @Nathan, with last_insert_id, will that capture the `BusinessID` when I'm inserting into `Business`, or would it take `ContactID` which I will have inserted in the first statement?

Comment: phpMyAdmin isn't a database, it's a tool database administrators use to manage their databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the value assigned to an AUTO_INCREMENT column when a row is inserted, MySQL provides a `last_insert_id()` function.

Immediately following a successful insert that assigned a value to an AUTO_INCREMENT column, in the same session, before any other SQL statements are issued, you can run a query:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

The value returned from that can be used in a subsequent INSERT. In your scenario, that value can be supplied as the value for the foreign key column.

Comment: Makes sense, select and store it before running any further `Insert` statements

Comment: Right. The `INSERT` statements don't run simultaneously. They run consecutively. Some MySQL client libraries have "wrapper functions" for that `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` statement, for example [`mysqli_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php), which makes for cleaner code. (Getting that auto_increment value is a one-liner *after* the code has verified that the insert was successful.) It should go without saying... you'd only use `mysqli_insert_id` if you're using mysqli_ interface functions. Not if you using PDO, or if you're using (shudder) the deprecated mysql_ functions...